# Chinese equivalent of "Oh Burn"

Tags: translation, word-requests

As stated in the title, what would be the Chinese equivalent of the popularly-used term (for kids) "Oh BURN"?  I understand it should be used mostly after an insult.  I Googled and found nothing but pictures of burnt stuff...

EDIT: yes it is the retort after (or followed by) an insult.  One will normal see this instead: "Ohhhh Burn!!!!"

Comment: You should probably explain a bit more about the context of "oh, burn," is it a retort to an insult. Can you update the question with an example?

Comment: @TommieC. I have updated the question.  I am not sure what could I input to make it more clear.

Comment: Can you explain "oh burn" a little more? Can I use "fxxk u" instead?

Comment: @wuyefeibao Here is a link to the usage in context: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hX8V9.jpg. Someone pointed out to me that the phrase is a third-party expression with no malicious connotations. It's a jocular expression of amusement at someone else having just been owned (A term used when someone gets embarrassed by someone else; commonly used when an individual gets beaten when gaming or playing a sport; a variation of pwned). I have never heard a Chinese person engage in this kind of chat, but it will be interesting to hear what others have to say...

Comment: I still don't get it. Is it like rejoice watching others burn and stirring it up in your mind?

Comment: `Monica` insults `Joey`. Onlooker `Chandler` watches the exchange between `Monica` and `Joey`, and says "Burn!" to mean: "I acknowledge `Monica's` insult as not just a quality insult, but also an amusing/funny one. `Joey`, you just got served (a dish of insult justice.)" Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the scenario that a third party witnessed an insult of others two, or someone try to lighthearted fight back a insult, maybe "雷死了"（lei2 si3 le) in Chinese can fit in. "雷" means Thunder.  "雷死了" means someone think it's somewhat funny unbelievable and be shocked.

A longer version is "雷得外焦里嫩" (Lei2 De Wai4 Jiao1 Li3 Nen4), which means someone got attached by thunder and lightning, and he got BURNed outside, but inside is still tender (think case of  overfired BBQ...) Maybe a picture can help to explain this situation better (found on internet)

[image]

Comment: I can't stop laughing with your picture!!  It fits the term so perfectly hah!  So I think 雷 is used instead of fire, in a same way things are..'burn'

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't a term in Chinese that will fit the slang.  A slightly different respond might be "应啊" in Cantonese

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can expect local slang to be readily available in other languages, so you would need to invent it: 燃烧吧！

Comment: I like your creativity

Answer (score 1):

I understand where you are coming from, I am not sure if the Chinese really have a direct translation but based off what you are saying (Taking a leap of faith here) You are looking for something along the lines of these two things: one translation(Again these are not direct) would be "you got told," which is 你被告知 "ni bei gaozhi"
Or the other "that must burn your feelings," 必须燃烧你的感受 "bixu ranshao ni de ganshou"
Again I am not completely fluent with the Chinese language but this should help you get an idea of what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate equivalent in Chinese for "Oh burn!" shall be "Kao !" which is most used and does not necessarily carry too much of the offensive while being able to express the subtle feeling in such a context.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an English slang responding to insults, I suggest (informal slang too, of course) "頂你呀!" in Cantonese.

For Mandarin, I am not sure because I am not a native speaker.  Perhaps people may simply respond with a single "干!".  Would anyone please correct me.

Comment: Henry I think that's the respond from the people being insulted, usually it's a third person saying it.  But thanks for your input too

Answer (score 0):

"Oh burn" is equivalent to:

呀!燒著了!

or

噢!燒著了!

or

噢!燃燒吧!

it has many ways to describe in chinese

Comment: The translation cannot convey the original meaning.